# JSP Syntax error when trying to embed a a-href

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have this JSP code for my web app:

I am getting a syntax error at `"<a href="welcome.html">Delete</a>"` in the success clause. Can anyone help me to pinpoint the problem? Thank you, appreciate it!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>atozknowledge.com demo loginjsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
    <%
String userid=request.getParameter("usr"); 
session.putValue("userid",userid); 
String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tomcat","root","root"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users where userid='"+userid+"'"); 
if(rs.next()) 
{ 
if(rs.getString(2).equals(pwd)) 
{ 
out.println("welcome"+userid); 
<a href="welcome.html">Delete</a>


} 
else 
{ 
out.println("Invalid password try again"); 
} 
} 
else 
%>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't intend to answer the question itself then please don't comment at all. I don't care if it's scary or not, and I don't want your suggestions.

Thank you and goodbye. @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="welcome.html">Delete</a>` isn't valid Java code. If you want to get out of the Java scriptlet, use `%>` to do so (then `<%` to go back into it):

```
%><a href="welcome.html">Delete</a><%
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is inserted inside a Java Part of code. Juste move your tag or close your scriptlet

```
if(rs.getString(2).equals(pwd)) 
{ 
out.println("welcome"+userid); 
%>
<a href="welcome.html">Delete</a>
<%

} 
else 
{ 
out.println("Invalid password try again"); 
}
```